# The constructor ArrayAdapter<string> is undefined

Tags: android, undefined, android-arrayadapter

I have a method, `initializeViews`, which encounters an **`ArrayAdapter constructor undefined` error** in its last line.

The method is located in `F1Fragment`, which extends `MainFragment`. `MainFragment` is then attached to an `Activity`.

Can we not give the context of a `Fragment` in the `ArrayAdapter<string>` constructor? I am new to Android. Please correct me. Thanks in advance.

```
private void initializeViews(RelativeLayout contentLayout) {
    leaguesListView = ( ListView ) contentLayout.findViewById ( R.id.leaguesListView );
    progressLinear  =   (LinearLayout) contentLayout.findViewById ( R.id.progressLeagues );
    values= new String[] { "RedBullRacing", "McLaren", "Lotus",
      "ForceIndia", "HRT", "Ferrari" };
    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(F1Fragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Change `F1Fragment.this` to `getActivity()`. The `Fragment` is not a `Context`.